# XMLStreamReader to print

Tags: java, xml

I am using `XMLStreamReader` to read an XML file and look for a specific element then update the corresponding value.

My question is that is there a way I can print each element, including the start of the document such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

every time I do `reader.next()`?

For example:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                file));
while(reader.hasNext())
reader.next().ToString() //Something like this?
...
```

Comment: `next()` returns an integer: "the integer code corresponding to the current parse event ".

Answer (score 2):

I am a little confused about what you are asking.

To print the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` you will have to handle the `START_DOCUMENT` event. You can call the following methods for this state:

```
next(), getEncoding(), getVersion(), isStandalone(), standaloneSet(), getCharacterEncodingScheme(), nextTag()
```

To print the name of the element that was most previously read whenever you do a `next()` call:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                   file));
String currentElement = "";
while(reader.hasNext()) {
   int next = reader.next();

   ..
   if(next == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT){
        currentElement = reader.getLocalName();
   ..

   System.out.println(currentElement );
}
```

Or, if you are interested in just printing out all of the data from the XML file, you need to handle each event accordingly:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                file));
while(reader.hasNext()) {
   int next = reader.next();

   ..
   if(next == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT){
        System.out.println(reader.getLocalName());
   }
   else if(next == XMLStreamReader.ATTRIBUTE) {
        // Print out all the attributes
   }
   else if(next == XMLStreamReader.COMMENT) {
        // Print the comment
   }
   ..

}
```

For a full list of events, reference the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html).